# Adding a computer to a server's domain (in windows)

Tags: dns, active-directory, domain

So I have a server and a computer.
Server's hostname:(for this example) Name1
On the computer in cmd I do: `/netdom join Name1 /domain:W2K8AD1Name1.local` and it gives me this error:

> The network path was not found, This command failed to complete successfully.

I've got it all set up, all the ip addresses are correct, all the names and everything. I've triple checked!

Also I've done: `/netdom join Name1 /domain:W2K8AD1Name1.local /userd:administrator passwordd:Password123` (this example being my admin password) to give it administrative credentials.

I just cannot connect this computer to the server!
For more details, I'm looking at: Lab 3.1(page 28, step 23) Installing Active Directory Domain Services and Joining a Server Core Server  BOOK TITLE: Lab Manual for MCTS Guide to Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Active Directory Configuration - Greg Tomsho

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not setted up the dns correctly. Set the dns servers on the computer to the IP of the server. Then it will work.